# procedure to check for non-existing row in foreign table(oracle)

Tags: oracle

I have to write a procedure to check for two things:
One is to check for duplicate country_id in countries table and if present,values should not be inserted.(country_Id is primary so it can't be duplicated)
2)Check for non-existing region_id (from a different table where region_Id is also pk but we have to have the region id in regions table before inserting a corresponding value in countries table.)

I have written the procedure for the first requirement.However,I can't seem to get the idea how to check for the second condition.

Can someone please guide me on this?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_vals (c_cntry_id OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
  c_cntry_id := user_seq.currval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
END;
```

Comment: try foreign key constraint

Comment: thanks,do you have some guidance for writing that code?

Answer (score 0):

Can define a foreign key constraint on countries "pointing" to regions:

```
ALTER TABLE countries
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (REGION_ID)
   REFERENCES regions (REGION_ID)
```

With this, if you attempt to insert (or update) a row in countries with a region id that does not exist in regions, the insert(update) will fail.  Also won't be allowed to delete regions whose ID is referenced in countries.  If you want to allow that, you'll have to add `ON DELETE <CASCADE | SET NULL>`.  `CASCADE` means also delete the row from other table, so if you delete a region, all countries for that region would be deleted.  `SET NULL` will just set all region IDs in countries table to NULL when region is deleted.

In you're stored proc, if you want to catch the error when this is violated, you'll have to add the appropriate exception definition, which I don't recall.

Comment: Yes,I already have this constraint.I was only asking how to write the SP for checking if that regionId exists in my regions table?

Comment: SELECT REGION_ID into rgn_id FROM regions where REGION_ID = c_rgn_id

Comment: if c_rgn_id already exists, rng_id will equal c_rgn_id.  If not, then rgn_id will be NULL.